# Can not run full SQL File but can run it piece meal for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql file I am trying to run on SQL Server 2014.  It looks like this -

```
USE MyDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[AnalyzerGroups];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AnalyzerGroups] (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY,
    [Product] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 1--default is 1 because when an item is first created we assume we want it enabled.
);

ALTER SCHEMA [MySchema]
TRANSFER [dbo].[AnalyzerGroups];

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[Analyzers]
ADD [A_Group_Id] int default null;

INSERT INTO MySchema.AnalyzerGroups (Product, Name, Enabled)
VALUES (9, 'Default LHE Group', 1);


INSERT INTO MySchema.AnalyzerGroups (Product, Name, Enabled)
VALUES (10, 'Default GHE Group', 1);

UPDATE MySchema.Analyzers
SET [A_Group_Id]=1
WHERE Product=9;

UPDATE MySchema.Analyzers
SET [A_Group_Id]=2
WHERE Product=10;
```

When I try to run this, I get the error `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24 Invalid column name 'A_Group_Id'.`  Which is referring to `UPDATE MySchema.Analyzers SET [A_Group_Id]=1 WHERE Product=9;`.

However, if I make a new query window and do each of these commands one at a time, it works fine, and that's how I have been doing things thus far.  What is wrong in my file where it doesn't want to work in one go?

Comment: If this code is intended to be executed inside SSMS itself then you can insert the `GO` batch separator in strategic positions, such as after the `alter table` statement. Use of the `GO` keyword is a syntax error in many other tools, though.

Comment: Oh ok.  I'm new to SQL Server.  When is the appropriate place for `GO`?  After each command

Comment: Why do you create your table in the dbo schema and then immediately move it to the MySchema schema and then start fiddling with the table by altering it? And why are you hard-coding ID values in your added column when you have a perfectly good identity column? For that matter, why is there no primary key in your table and no foreign key from Analyzers to AnalyzerGroups? I think you need to get some help with your general schema design. To answer you question - add GO after each statement.

Comment: @SMor not by choice.  This particulate database that I did not design and is over 10 years old has a stored procedure where no matter what schema you originally make a table in, it automatically gets transferred to dbo anyways.  So I may as well make it in dbo  and then transfer it.  Also, they have a convention of not using foreign keys ( I know lol).  I don't see where I am hardcoding IDs, just setting the faux foreign key A_Group_Id,  but both do have an id column.  This is for a very large company and it's been in production over a decade, I'm just following the standards set before me.